# Rviz broken, no transform from child frame to parent frame

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

I have just found that my rviz is broken. With several messages `no transform from [child_frame] to [parent_frame]`. Sorry, I cannot post screenshots.

Any idea to fix this?

Ar.

Note: I have done the test with rrbot, the gazebo test package and my own robot model.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/82106/rviz-broken,-no-transform-from-child-frame-to-parent-frame/) by [Arn-O](https://answers.ros.org/users/5387/arn-o/) on ROS Answers with karma: 107 on 2013-09-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was in fact missing the following package:

`ros-hydro-robot-state-publisher`

I do not understand how it has disappeared.

---

Originally posted by [Arn-O](https://answers.ros.org/users/5387/arn-o/) with karma: 107 on 2013-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0